# oracle expression computed length

Tags: sql, oracle

When Oracle creates a view for a query it calculates a data type and data length for the view which can be queried from `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.`

Is there a function that gives access to these computed values without needing to create the view?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEMP AS 
select 'This is a string. ' || 2020 || ' Another string' TEMP_COL from dual;

select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TEMP';
```

Comment: Huh?  If there is no view, then there is no "computed value".

Comment: `select length('This is a string. ' || 2020 || ' Another string') from dual` ? Or if you want other data types, maybe `dump(<expression>)`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: May be `DUMP()`? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#i77278

Comment: I think DUMP() or maybe VSIZE() is my best option. I thought the view creation was calculating appropriate column length at compile time but I just proved myself wrong. I'll have to use some function to find the character length at run time.

Comment: It does calculate the data length for string columns when it is defined, based on what it knows about the expression. If it's built from constants it uses those (in your example making data_length 37); if it concatenates columns from other tables it uses their lengths to work out how big it can get. I still don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have user provided SELECT statements that need to be inserted into a predefined table. If the worst case field length in the SELECT exceeds the table length then I need to flag the SELECT. It was suggested to me that the VIEW create calculates the worst case field length. I was able to create a VIEW that underestimates the field length of a column using a SELECT with FUNCTION calls. I can always run the insert and see if it fails but my requirement is to catch problems before that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBMS_SQL to parse a query and obtain the column names, data types and lengths/scale.

```
declare
  PROCEDURE temp (p_query IN VARCHAR2) IS
    col_cnt     INTEGER;
    rec_tab     dbms_sql.desc_tab2;
    v_tab       dbms_sql.varchar2s;
    v_cursor    NUMBER;
    v_line      varchar2(100);
    v_datatype  varchar2(100);
  BEGIN
    v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, p_query, 1);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns2(v_cursor, col_cnt, rec_tab);
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor);
    FOR v_pos in 1..rec_tab.LAST LOOP
      v_datatype :=
            case rec_tab(v_pos).col_type
                  when 1   THEN  'VARCHAR2'
                  when 2   THEN  'NUMBER'
                  when 8   THEN  'LONG'
                  when 9   THEN  'VARCHAR'
                  when 12  THEN  'DATE'
                  when 23  THEN  'RAW'
                  when 24  THEN  'LONG RAW'
                  when 69  THEN  'ROWID'
                  when 96  THEN  'CHAR'
                  when 100 THEN  'BINARY_FLOAT'
                  when 101 THEN  'BINARY_DOUBLE'
                  when 112 THEN  'CLOB'
                  when 113 THEN  'BLOB'
                  when 114 THEN  'BFILE'
                  when 115 THEN  'CFILE'
                  when 178 THEN  'TIME'
                  when 179 THEN  'TIME WITH TIME ZONE'
                  when 180 THEN  'TIMESTAMP'
                  when 181 THEN  'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE'
                  when 231 THEN  'TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE'
                  when 182 THEN  'INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH'
                  when 183 THEN  'INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND'
                  when 208 THEN  'UROWID'
                  else           'OTHER:'||rec_tab(v_pos).col_type
            end;
      if rec_tab(v_pos).col_precision > 0 and rec_tab(v_pos).col_scale > 0 then
        v_datatype := v_datatype||'('||rec_tab(v_pos).col_precision||','||rec_tab(v_pos).col_scale||')';
      elsif rec_tab(v_pos).col_precision > 0 and v_datatype != 'NUMBER' then
        v_datatype := v_datatype||'('||rec_tab(v_pos).col_precision||')';
      elsif rec_tab(v_pos).col_max_len > 0 and v_datatype != 'NUMBER' then
        v_datatype := v_datatype||'('||rec_tab(v_pos).col_max_len||')';
      else
        v_datatype := v_datatype;
      end if;
      v_line := rpad(rec_tab(v_pos).col_name,32)||
                rpad(v_datatype,32);
      dbms_output.put_line(v_line);
    END LOOP;
  END;
BEGIN
  temp( q'{select 'This is a string. ' || 2020 || ' Another string' TEMP_COL from dual }' );
END;
/
```